# randomly choose one data from blocks of query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 100000 records in a table. I need to make a query that reads 10 records and after that 10 more records continuously until the end of the table. For each of the 10 rows groups, I need to pick one random row. Is it possible to accomplish that using a MySQL query? I need some idea to do this. Can anybody help me?

I have tried to do a php loop but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
include_once ("connection.php");

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trying");
$result = array();


while ($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
    array_push($result, array('no'=> $data2['no'],
                      'source'=> $data2['source'],
                 'destination'=> $data2['destination']));
}

$e=0;   
for ($a = 0; $a <= 49;)
{

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++,$a++) {
        $rand = array();
        $rand[$i] = $result[$a];


    }
    echo json_encode($rand[1]);

}

?>
```

Comment: You want sequential groups of 10 and a random from within that set?

Comment: What happened with braces after `while` statement?

Comment: Goat CO, yes exactly. can you help?

Comment: bartek, the result just come out with one data which is the last data of the 100000th.

Comment: the  100000 row array would be a little large, i would put the query in a loop and retrieve X at a time

Comment: Dagon. thank you. i have thought that before, but i dont know how to do it. i'm still new in this language.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of this:

```
for ($a = 0; $a <= 49;)
{

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++,$a++) {
        $rand = array();
        $rand[$i] = $result[$a];


    }
    echo json_encode($rand[1]);

}
```

you can use this:

```
$rand = array();
$step = 10;

for ($min = 0; $min <= 49; $min = $min + $step)
{   
    $max = $min + $step;
    $rand[] = $result[rand($min,$max)];
}
echo json_encode($rand);
```

Comment: Please tell me if is helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're echoing a json encoded array, I'm assuming you're calling this php file through an AJAX request, and you want subsequent requests for each 10 rows.

If this is the case, a solution to your problem could be this:

1. Define limit and offset as vars in your javascript
2. Pass limit and offset with the AJAX request
3. If the result of the AJAX request isn't empty, increment offset by limit (offset = offset + limit) to use in the next request
4. Receive limit and offset in the PHP file (use $_GET or $_POST, depends on the type of request)
5. Include limit and offset in the MySQL query ("SELECT * FROM trying LIMIT $offset, $limit")
6. Calculate a random number from 0 to 9 (rand(0, 9))
7. Fetch the nth (rand) row from the MySQL result (see solution below)

Your PHP file should look like this:

```
include_once ("connection.php");
$limit = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['limit']); // If post use $_POST
$offset = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['offset']); // If post use $_POST
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trying LIMIT $offset, $limit");
$rand = rand(0, 9);
$count = 0;
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    if($rand == $count++) {
        echo json_encode($row);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Richardo Nunes, thank you. i will try it right away :)

Comment: No problem :) If you also need help with the javascript code (steps 1 to 3), please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Put the SQL statement in a loop and use the counter as a variable in the Limit:

```
$count = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trying");
$total = round(mysql_num_rows($count) / 10);

for ($i=0;$i<$total;$i++) {
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trying LIMIT ".($i * 10).", 10");
$result = array();


while ($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
    array_push($result, array('no'=> $data2['no'],
                      'source'=> $data2['source'],
                 'destination'=> $data2['destination']));
}
}

$e=0;   
for ($a = 0; $a <= 49;)
{

for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++,$a++) {
    $rand = array();
    $rand[$i] = $result[$a];


}
echo json_encode($rand[1]);

}


?>
```

Comment: Just the first 5 lines are all that is important, I did not pay too much attention to where the closing bracket was placed. That you will have to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
include_once ("connection.php");

$per = 10;
$start = 0;
$total = 0;

$total_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM trying");
if(mysql_num_rows($total_query) == 1) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($total_query);

    $total = $row['total'];

    $offset = ($start * $per);

    $results = array();
    while($offset <= $total) {
        $tmp = array();

        $data_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trying LIMIT ".$offset.",".$per);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data_query)) {
            array_push($tmp, array(
                'no'=> $row['no'],
                'source'=> $row['source'],
                'destination'=> $row['destination'])
            );
        }

        array_push($results,$tmp[rand(0,9)]);
        unset($tmp);

        $start++;
        $offset = ($start * $per);
    }

    echo json_encode($results);
} else {
    die("No records found.");
}
?>
```

Comment: made one change. forgot to output json :D

Comment: line 10, mysql_num_rows($total) warning parameter 1 to be resource, integer given. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following:

```
<?php
include_once ("connection.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM trying";
$count = 0;

while(true)
{

    $data = mysql_query($query." LIMIT ".$count.",10");

    $random = rand(1,10);
    for($i=1;$i<=$random;$i++)
    {
       $row =  mysql_fetch_array($data);
        if($row === false)
        {
            break 2;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($row);

    $count++;
}

?>
```